# Как отучить Yii2 удалять cookie?

Tags: php, cookie, yii2

Суть:
Yii2 все куки и сессии удаляет через некоторое время, хотя время жизни 3600*24*30*12 - что подтверждается при просмотре кук в браузере.
Удаляет и PHPSESSID и любые другие на домене

Мой конфиг:

```
'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'cookieParams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 3600*24*30*12],
            'timeout' => 3600*24*30*12,
            'useCookies' => true,
        ],
'request' => [
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'секретка',
        ],
```

Валидацию отключил т.к. пробовал задавать через setcookie напрямую.
Момент удаления отследить не смог, но он наступает через какое-то время после неактивности клиента, примерно 20 минут.

Так же выяснил что удаляются все куки, если удалить вручную PHPSESSID.

Comment: `все куки и сессии удаляет через некоторое время` - Так сессия должна удаляться при закрытии браузера по идеи

Comment: Где крутиться ваше приложение yii2? Отдельный сервер или хостинг, на машине которого возможно хостяться другие люди? Вообще, если на хостинге есть несколько сайтов, то настройки кук могут чистить куки всех сайтов на сервере. Чтобы такого не происходило необходимо указывать папку для кук.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно дело не в `yii`.
Такое поведение встречается из-за неверного или отсутствующего значения параметра `session.cookie_domain php.ini`, который можно установить:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".site.com"
```

Или:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.site.com' );
```